# Making DIVs go from inline-block, to an "offset stack" responsively

Tags: html, css

I'm currently struggling to make my `<div>` elements go from being aligned in inline-block to going to a mobile offset stacked divs.

Currently I have my text scaling down when at less when the screen is less than 1000px. It all works fine, however, as I mentioned the text is too small on mobile. I hope to up the mobile font size and add a measure so that the  elements can align on a line break.

An example of what I'm trying to achieve is below.

[image]

My current HTML:

```css
.highlights-banner-background {
  /* Background coloured Div in banner */
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.highlights-banner-inner {
  /* Div that holds text in  */
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

.highlights_banner_item-1,
.highlights_banner_item-2,
.highlights_banner_item-3,
.highlights_banner_item-4 {
  /* Each item of text in banner */
  display: inline-block;
  width: 24%;
  vertical-align: center;
  float: center;
}

.highlights_banner_item-1,
.highlights_banner_item-2,
.highlights_banner_item-3,
.highlights_banner_item-4 {
  font-size: 14px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 53px) {
  .highlights_banner_item-1,
  .highlights_banner_item-2,
  .highlights_banner_item-3,
  .highlights_banner_item-4 {
    font-size: calc(9px + 6 * ((100vw - 320px) / 680));
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .highlights_banner_item-1,
  .highlights_banner_item-2,
  .highlights_banner_item-3,
  .highlights_banner_item-4 {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 200px) {
  .highlights-banner-inner {
    padding-left,
    padding-right: calc(8px + 6 * ((100vw - 320px) / 680));
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .highlights-banner-inner {
    padding-left,
    padding-right: 50px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 200px) {
  .highlights-banner-background {
    height: calc(60px + 6 * ((100vw - 320px) / 680));
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .highlights-banner-background {
    height: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="highlights-banner-background">
  <div class="highlights-banner-inner">
    <div class="highlights_banner_item-1">
      Div 1
    </div>
    <div class="highlights_banner_item-2">
      Div 2
    </div>
    <div class="highlights_banner_item-3">
      Div 3
    </div>
    <div class="highlights_banner_item-4">
      Div 4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I edited your question so your code is 'runnable,' hopefully it reproduces your problem accurately? Incidentally this isn't a solution to your problem but your CSS syntax is flawed in two places that I can see `padding-left, padding-right:` CSS doesn't allow this, that's a syntax error which causes those property declarations to be discarded; each property-value has to be declared individually, to give: `padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 50px;` There are other ways, of course, see: [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding). Thank you for adding the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you something like this

Here using **flex property**

```css
.container{
 padding:10px;
 border:1px solid #ccc;
 background:#fff7f5;
 display:flex;
}
.item{
  border:1px solid #111;
  background:#fff;
  margin:10px;
  max-width: calc(25% - 22px); /* minus the margin and border */
  flex: 1 1 calc(25% - 22px); /* minus the margin and border */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
  .item{
    max-width: calc(33% - 22px); /* minus the margin and border */
    flex: 1 1 calc(33% - 22px); /* minus the margin and border */
  }
  .container{
      flex-direction: row;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Div 1</div>
  <div class="item">Div 2</div>
  <div class="item">Div 3</div>
  <div class="item">Div 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use either display: flex, and set flex-wrap to wrap, or display: grid with auto-fill/fit in your css:

Flexbox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox

CSS Grid: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid